# HQL Subquery on a join table

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

New to HQL and I'm bashing my head against the wall!

How would I change this SQL query into HQL?

db.person_table is a join table generated by Hibernate.

```
SELECT * FROM db.username
WHERE id IN (SELECT person_id from db.person_table where person_id = 3);
```

I either end up getting an 
"illegal attempt to dereference collection"
or "not mapped by" error when converting it to HQL

Comment: please post your entities since HQL is related to those

Answer (score 1):

You can try with joins. Check on corresponding HQL implementation.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM db.username a 
INNER JOIN db.person_table b ON id = person_id 
WHERE person_id = 3;
```